# Is this a removable discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, singularity-theory

Consider the function
$$
f(x):=x\text{ mod }2\pi,~~x\in [0,2\pi). 
$$

Then obviously, $f$ is not defined for $x=2\pi$ but $\lim_{x^-\to 2\pi}f(x)=0$.

I am not sure whether $x=2\pi$ is a removable discontinuity.

I think this is the case of $\lim_{x\to 2\pi}f(x)$ exists but I am not sure what $\lim_{x^+\to 2\pi}f(x)$ is (how can $x^+\to 2\pi$ make any sense if $x\in [0,2\pi)$?) resp. if it coincides with $\lim_{x^-\to 2\pi}f(x)=0$.

Comment: What purpose does that “mod $2\pi$” serve if you impose the condition $x \in [0,2 \pi)$ anyway? You don't mean $x \in \mathbf{R}$, by any chance? (In that case, you get a jump discontinuity, which is not a removable singularity.)

Comment: In case $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I do not see why the one-sided limit from the positive direction does not equal $0$ ( I think this is the condition for "jump discontinuity").

Comment: You are basically saying that$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in[0,2\pi)\\\text{undefined},&x\notin[0,2\pi)\end{cases}$$And you intend to ask what $\lim\limits_{x\to2\pi}f(x)$ is, despite major domain issues?

Comment: You also propose that $\lim\limits_{x\to2\pi^-}f(x)=0$, but as far as I can tell, $f(x)$ is increasing and $f(1)=1$, hence, $\lim\limits_{x\to2\pi^-}f(x)>1$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+mod+2pi

Comment: Ok, but now I am confused since at $2\pi$, the function should jump to $0$.

Comment: So lets assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as Hans Lundmark suggests. Why is then $x=2\pi$ a jump discontinuity? And what are the one-sided limits? I am confused

Comment: Okay, I would think that the left-onesided limit is indeed not 0 but the right-one-sided limit is 0.

Comment: That's right, you would have $f(2\pi) = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to (2\pi)^+} f(x) = 0$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to (2\pi)^-} f(x) = 2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is 'ill-posed' because discontinuity points are generally assumed to be in the interior of the domain of continuity. Being at the frontier, your point cannot be 'eliminated' by defining the value of the function there as the limit of the function there, simply because there's no two-sided limit at that point.
You surely can readapt the canonical definitions to your needs but I think you'll hardly come up with something useful (you would be limited to this kind of context, where your function has whole intervals removed from its domain).
Also definitions are just names used to refer to commonly used things, but that doesn't mean that your point can't be interesting anyway.

Comment: This "answer" will be rendered meaningless if/when the asker works to clarify the question. You could have left a comment to this effect: "The question is 'ill-posed' "  any way, as currently stated, I think your "answer" is rather unclear.